# set mysql connection behind ssh in groovy script SoapUI

Tags: mysql, groovy, ssh, soapui

From groovy script in SoapUI I need to connect to a mysql database to perform some queries. The problem is that due to security reasons no external access is possible. 
Therefore it is required to get an ssh access (like a tunnel) and invoke mysql locally.

Initially I was reading the below project properties and then connect to mysql:

```
ServerUrl=jdbc:mysql://10.255.255.122:3306/db
ServerDbUser=user
ServerDbPwd=password
ServerDriver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

def url=testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("ServerUrl")
def usr=testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("ServerDbUser")
def pwd=testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("ServerDbPwd")
def driver=testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("ServerDriver")

com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils.registerJdbcDriver(driver)
sqlServer = Sql.newInstance(url, usr, pwd, driver)`
```

But this didn't work so now it is required to establish first a ssh connection to the server with the IP 10.255.255.122 and then open the mysql connection locally. So I guess the Server Url will change to:

`ServerUrl=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db`

But I don't know how to set first the ssh connection to the server.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?t=15400 and [connect to remote mysql database through ssh using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968293/connect-to-remote-mysql-database-through-ssh-using-java)

It will give you an idea about implementing it in soapUI.

Below is the code by [Ripon Al Wasim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/617450/ripon-al-wasim) which is available as an answer at the stackoverflow link mentioned above

```
package mypackage;
import java.sql.*;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

public class UpdateMySqlDatabase {
    static int lport;
    static String rhost;
    static int rport;
    public static void go(){
        String user = "ripon";
        String password = "wasim";
        String host = "myhost.ripon.wasim";
        int port=22;
        try
            {
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
            lport = 4321;
            rhost = "localhost";
            rport = 3306;
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            System.out.println("Establishing Connection...");
            session.connect();
            int assinged_port=session.setPortForwardingL(lport, rhost, rport);
            System.out.println("localhost:"+assinged_port+" -> "+rhost+":"+rport);
            }
        catch(Exception e){System.err.print(e);}
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            go();
        } catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
          System.out.println("An example for updating a Row from Mysql Database!");
          Connection con = null;
          String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
          String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + rhost +":" + lport + "/";
          String db = "testDB";
          String dbUser = "wasim";
          String dbPasswd = "riponalwasim123";
          try{
          Class.forName(driver);
          con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+db, dbUser, dbPasswd);
          try{
          Statement st = con.createStatement();
          String sql = "UPDATE MyTableName " +
                  "SET email = 'ripon.wasim@smile.com' WHERE email='peace@happy.com'";

          int update = st.executeUpdate(sql);
          if(update >= 1){
          System.out.println("Row is updated.");
          }
          else{
          System.out.println("Row is not updated.");
          }
          }
          catch (SQLException s){
          System.out.println("SQL statement is not executed!");
          }
          }
          catch (Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
          }
          }
        }
```

Comment: Useful links... I'll see if I can translate this to SoapUI groovy script.
Thanks

Comment: you probably wouldn't have to change a lot and just be able to reuse most of this code. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I thought this can be done easier, without importing java and java secure channel...

Comment: Well you can create an SSh using groovy too...check out this post http://www.randomactsofsentience.com/2012/02/using-groovy-script-to-ssh-tunnel-to.html

Comment: I tried the code from your solution and I get this error: `Thu Apr 10 12:03:38 EEST 2014:INFO:com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: PortForwardingL: local port 127.0.0.1:4321 cannot be bound.`

Comment: unfortunately i cannot debug this problem at my end...however google gave me this http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/unable-to-allocate-port-with-port-forwarding-software-616616/

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Is it still the `cannot be bound` error?