# JDBC - connecting to a remote MySQL database on a specific port

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, remote-access

So normally, you would use this:

```
 Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://[ip:mysqlport]/[databasename]?user=[user]&password=[password]");
```

However, I need to connect to an IP using a specific port *in addition* to specifying the MySQL port as well. I tried ip:serverport:mysqlport, but it didn't work.

**Edit: Nevermind, I was misunderstanding something.**

Comment: What do you mean by "in addition", a connection to mysql will only be on one port.  do you mean you are using a proxy or something?

Comment: I find it unclear what you are trying to do. You can only connect to one port.

Comment: Nevermind, I was misunderstanding something.

Comment: It is either a direct connection then you have only 1 port. Or you should be using a ssh tunnel and thus should actually be connecting to localhost, in which case you'd want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968293/connect-to-remote-mysql-database-through-ssh-using-java

Answer (score 2):

Try structuring it like this and see if it helps

```
Connection conn = 
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.1:5000/myDB", "admin", "admin");
```

Comment: @ YCF_L 100% correct, was a miss type. Thanks for the edit. Nice spot!!