# Hive is not getting connected after getting connected to ec2-linux instance

Tags: java, jdbc, hive, putty, jsch

This is the Putty image:

[image]

I tried to connect to my Putty and was able to connect, then trying to connect to Hive with JDBC, but still facing the same connection issue. Here's my code.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

public class SSHFile2 {

    static int lport;
    static String rhost;
    static int rport;
    public static void go(){
        String user = "ec2-user";
        //String password = "";
        String host = "18.188.88.49";
        int port=22;
        try
            {
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
            lport = 4321;
            rhost = "localhost";
            rport = 10000;
            //session.setPassword(password);
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            System.out.println("Establishing Connection...");
            session.connect();
            int assinged_port=session.setPortForwardingL(lport, rhost, rport);
            System.out.println("localhost:"+assinged_port+" -> "+rhost+":"+rport);
            }
        catch(Exception e){System.err.print(e);}
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            go();
        } catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
          System.out.println("An example for updating a Row from Hive Database!");
          Connection con = null;
          String driver = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
          String url = "jdbc:hive2://" + rhost +":" + lport + "/";
          String db = "sahoo";
          String dbUser = "hive";
          String dbPasswd = "";
          try{
          Class.forName(driver);
          con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+db, dbUser, dbPasswd);
          try{
          Statement st = con.createStatement();
          System.out.println("Connected to Hive");
          /*String sql = "UPDATE MyTableName " +
                  "SET email = 'ripon.wasim@smile.com' WHERE email='peace@happy.com'";

          int update = st.executeUpdate(sql);
          if(update >= 1){
          System.out.println("Row is updated.");
          }
          else{
          System.out.println("Row is not updated.");
          }
*/          }
          catch (SQLException s){
          System.out.println("SQL statement is not executed!");
          }
          }
          catch (Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
          }
          }

}
```

After this I got this message. Although I'm not aware of the Lport, what to use exactly for Hive.

This is the error report:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth failApr 18, 2019 4:56:00 PM org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils parseURL
INFO: Supplied authorities: localhost:4321
Apr 18, 2019 4:56:00 PM org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils parseURL
INFO: Resolved authority: localhost:4321
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".

INFO: Transport Used for JDBC connection: null
java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://localhost:4321/sahoo: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:231)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:176)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You seem to have a false idea, that by opening SSH connection in JSch, the database client will magically be able to connect to a remote database, whoch is not directly accessible. It won't.

Comment: No I thought if I can connect to the SSH connection, my hive environment is also setup there only, so it might be a help. Can you please help me in this connection? your mentioned link didn't work for me.

Comment: I do not understand the explanation in your comment -- Anyway, *"didn't work for me"* does not work for us as a problem description. Did you try the code from the answer by @RiponAlWasim?

Comment: No, I tried the first one. Can you tell me what will be my localport for Hive? Remote port will be 10000, but what will be my lport? @MartinPrikryl

Comment: I've updated the question in the comment, can you please tell me where I'm doing wrong? I'm new to this thing, that's why not aware much. please need help much. @MartinPrikryl

Comment: Note the `rhost = "localhost"` in the `url`, while you use `host = "18.188.88.49"`.

Comment: Because it's hosted in that ip address, 18.188.88.49, it's an ec2 linux instance.

Comment: Sure, the same way the database is actually on `myhost.ripon.wasim` in the code by @RiponAlWasim . But you need to connect to the **local end** of the SSH tunnel, which leads to `18.188.88.49` on the **remote** end. Just do, what the answer by @RiponAlWasim does.

Comment: I have posted a simple example there: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1968293/850848#55744561

Comment: int forwardedPort = jumpboxSession.setPortForwardingL(0, databaseHost, databasePort);

you have added this line in your code. What will be databaseHost and databasePort for me? 
databasePort = 10000 maybe, and databaseHost should be localhost? or that ip? @MartinPrikryl

Comment: As my answer says *"The hostname/IP address and port, you would use **on the SSH server** to connect to the database."* + It should be `**session**.setPort...` - It's corrected already in the answer.

Comment: String databaseHost = "database.example.com";
And what about this? i didn't get this part. @MartinPrikryl

Comment: I cannot answer that for you. You have to know that. How do you connect to the database now?

Comment: If the database runs on the same machine as your SSH server, then use `localhost`.

Comment: Okay @MartinPrikryl, I've edited the question. Can you tell me now where I'm doing the mistake. I will add your part also if you want.

Comment: There are two different error messages in your question. Which one are you getting now?

Comment: If would also help, if you use my simple code. It way easier to follow than the one by @RiponAlWasim. + Also show us how you connect with PuTTY.

Comment: Both. first that JSch exception then ConnectionException. @MartinPrikryl

Comment: ohh sorry I forgot to add the method addIdentity(), when I added that for Jsch, that JSch exception is not there now. Only ConnectionException is still there. @MartinPrikryl

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192045/discussion-between-sayan-sahoo-and-martin-prikryl).